# Determine largest magnitude given a covariance matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

Let's say one has a univariate Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu = 0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

It is easy to see that the distance from $\mu$ to +1$\sigma$ is...well...$\sigma$.

Let's now say we have a bivariate Gaussian distribution with

$\vec{\mu} = {[ 0 \space 0]^T}$
and covariance matrix $\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{x,x}=var(X)         & \sigma_{y,x}=cov(Y,X)   \\
    \sigma_{x,y}=cov(X,Y)         & \sigma_{y,y}=var(Y)
\end{bmatrix} $

where  cov(X,Y) $\ne 0 $, and because cov. matrices are always symmetric, cov(X,Y)=cov(Y,X)

I am wanting to calculate the distance d (shown in picture)[image]

I understand that this distance is precisely the largest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix. Is there another method that one can use to determine d?

Update 1:
One way of doing this -I believe- is by finding the largest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix. I am looking for a method that does not use the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix.

Comment: I think beginning by looking at [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) may be a helpful starting point for you.

Comment: You refer to "another" method.  Which method are you currently using to find $d$ and why do you need another?

Comment: The method I talk about involves the calculation of the eigenvalues of the cov.matrix. Now, when I say method, I don't mean algorithm :). I imagine there are multiple algorithms that one can use to get the eigenvalues. I am looking for a method that does not use the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: I don't follow: your question asks for an eigenvalue of a matrix, but you would like a method that doesn't use eigenvalues??

Comment: are you missing a correlation coefficient in $\Sigma$? What you've got there is rank 1 so your problem reduces to the univariate case

Comment: @Chaconne I updated the cov. matrix so you can see that one can compute the correlation coefficient as cor(X,Y) = cov(X,Y)/ (std(X)*std(Y)).

Comment: @whuber Hi! I am saying that one way of finding d is by finding the eigenvalues of the cov. matrix, and the largest one -I believe- represents this distance. I am looking for another way of finding d that does not involve finding the eigenvalues.

Comment: @anr what whuber is explaining is that since the solution to this problem is finding the first eigenvalue, then any solution to this problem is a way of finding eigenvalues.  It is like asking "how can I calculate $1+1$ without using addition?"

Comment: This question would be a lot better if you explained why you don't want to calculate eigenvalues *in the usual way* so that we can propose solutions that fit your constraints.

Comment: @NeilG I see. Maybe that is the answer, that there is no way to find d without calculating the eigenvalues.

Comment: why don't you explain why you can't do it in the usual way?

Comment: Sure. I don't think I have a compelling reason other than the fact that I would have to justify why I am using one algorithm over another.

Comment: why would anyone care which algorithm you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56008/discussion-between-anr-and-neil-g).

Comment: anr, are you aware that the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix?  In particular, upon writing $$\Sigma=\pmatrix{a&b\\b&d}$$ the characteristic polynomial becomes $$p_\Sigma(x)=\operatorname{det}(\Sigma-x\mathbb{I})=(a-x)(d-x)-b^2.$$Its roots are found with any version of the quadratic formula. In one version the largest root is $$\lambda_{+}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a+d+\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4b^2}\right).$$ *Any* method you use to find it *must* be equivalent to this one.